# What happens to the previous window if I create a new window and makeKeyAndVisible

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to logout and go back to the Login Viewcontroller.

So I create a window, set rootViewController, then makeKeyAndVisible. (Not in AppDelegate)

```swift
class AppManager: NSObject {
var window: UIWindow?

func goToLoginPage() {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
    "LoginVC") as! LoginVC
    window?.rootViewController = loginVC
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}

}
```

It works, but I am thinking what will happen to the previous window. Will it be closed and released automatically? If not, do I need to do it?

Or is it better to directly use "UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!!" like the following instead of creating a new window?

```
UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!!.rootViewController = homeVC
```

Comment: Show where the `window` variable in that first set of code is coming from.

Comment: I create a variable in the class like this "var window: UIWindow?"

Comment: Where do you actually assign a UIWindow instance to that `window` variable?

Comment: Sorry, I've renewed the code.

Comment: It really is better not to do that. If there is only one screen you only need one UIWindow. If the problem is a one-time login page there are much better ways to do it.

Comment: I don't think so that initializing an instance can deinit old instance, so it will remain in memory which mean you are putting overhead which clearly means its a bad approach. Also this window will not be kind of shared window if you want to access new created window you have to do some extra work too, and much more reasons just try to think ... :)

Comment: So it's better to use UIApplication.shared.delegete?.window!! instead of creating a new window right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the existing window from the `AppDelegate` and change the `rootViewControlller`

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = appDelegate.window {
    window.rootViewController = loginVC
}
```